# NS-3 Python simulation

Tags: python, ns-3

I'm trying to work with ns-3 in python. I am specifically working on the `manet-routing-compare.cc` file in the example directory, and trying to convert it into Python code.

In `manet-routing-compare.cc`, line 379:

```
AddressValue remoteAddress(InetSocketAddress(adhocInterfaces.GetAddress(i), port));
```

I converted it to:

```
port = c_int(9)
remoteAddress = ns.network.AddressValue(ns.network.InetSocketAddress(adhocInterfaces.GetAddress(i), port.value))
```

But I got the following error:

```
TypeError: none of the 4 overloaded methods succeeded. Full details:
  AddressValue::AddressValue(ns3::AddressValue&&) =>
    ValueError: could not convert argument 1 (object is not an rvalue)
  AddressValue::AddressValue(const ns3::AddressValue&) =>
    TypeError: could not convert argument 1
  AddressValue::AddressValue() =>
    TypeError: takes at most 0 arguments (1 given)
  AddressValue::AddressValue(const ns3::Address& value) =>
    TypeError: could not convert argument 1
```

Any suggestions for solving this problem?

The following statement prints this:

```
print(ns.network.InetSocketAddress(adhocInterfaces.GetAddress(i), port.value))
02-07-0a:01:01:01:09:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Like responded on the ns-3-users forums, this is due to a Cppyy limitation that doesn't support a custom `operator Address`, requiring explicit conversion from the `InetSocketAddress` type to `Address`.

The conversion can be done via `InetSocketAddress().ConvertTo()` in ns-3.38 and onwards, or `ns.addressFromInetSocketAddress(InetSocketAddress())` in ns-3.37.

Link to forum posts
https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users/c/yQ3h_y235Es